# Command Explanation: mkdir -p /root/.ssh

Tags: directory, root

I came across a Bash script with with the following command:

```
$ mkdir -p /root/.ssh
```

I know what `mkdir -p` does, but, what is "/root/"? I thought root was '/'?

Comment: `/root` is typically the home directory for the user `root`

Comment: In the olden days, the home directory for `root` could have been the root of the filesystem tree at `/`, e.g. http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=passwd&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=SunOS+5.10&arch=default&format=html

Answer (score 6):

- '`/`' is the root of the filesystem.
- '`/root`' is the home directory for the root user.
- '`/root/.ssh`' is a hidden directory that will hold information used by `ssh`, like public/private keys (Note: the `.` makes it hidden).

If you're wondering why its not `/home/root` (like the other users) this is because /home is often a separate partition (and for security reasons should  be) but if that partition ever failed to mount it could inhibit the root user's ability to login. It's kind of like how you see `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` (or `/bin` and `/usr/bin`) you have binaries that are installed and execute at boot-time versus the user installed/executed binaries.

More info/source: http://www.linfo.org/slash_root.html

Answer (score 3):

"root" has a number of different meanings.

First, it is the username of the "superuser", the administrator of the computer, who has the power to do literally *anything* with the computer.  (He has much power than a Windows administrator, by the way, because the ENTIRETY of the Linux operating system can be changed, even down to editing the source code of the operating system itself.)

Next, root is the name for the "folder" which contains *all other folders and files* on the entire system.  (You say you're a Linux noob, so I used the word "folder", which is common in Windows and Mac OS X.  The Linux term is "directory", for reasons I won't go into here.)  The *root directory* is spelled `/` but is pronounced "the root directory".  If you are referring to something *inside* the root directory, you pronounce it "slash".  So `/home` is the name of a directory inside the root directory, and it is pronounced "slash home".

The word "root" can also mean "root privileges"—in other words, the system permissions which allow you to do absolutely anything on the system.  Example sentences: "You have to run the installer root."  (Although "...**as** root", referring to the root user, is the more usual way to say that.)

The word "root" can also be a verb, meaning "to acquire root privileges, usually illegitimately or against the intentions of the manufacturer."  Examples: "An attacker rooted my system and I had to reinstall."  "I got tired of the restrictions Samsung put on my phone, so I rooted it."

The definition of "root" which applies in the context you are asking about requires some preparation.  (Don't worry, it's not that difficult.)  Every user in Linux has a "home directory".  That is where all their files are stored, and they're not accessible to other users.  Since `root` is a user (the superuser), `root` has a home directory.  Most users have their home directory in `/home` (for instance, Jimmy would have his home directory at `/home/jimmy`, pronounced "slash home slash jimmy"), but for good technical reasons the root user's home directory needs to be in the root directory.  So "the root directory" refers to `/`, and "the root user's home directory" refers to `/root`, pronounced "slash root".

Don't feel bad about being confused at first—root has a LOT of meanings!  There may even be a couple more that I have missed.

(For the background on WHY the top level directory is called "the root directory", look into graph theory, and what a "tree" is in graph theory, and what the "root" of the tree is.  This is the derivation of the word, and also the reason why it is called a directory "tree", and why the "path" of a file is called a "path".  All these words and several others derive from mathematical terms in Graph Theory.)